# How to do a multiple match Binary Sort on a String Array?

Tags: java, search, binary

I'm attempting to create a Binary Search with multiple matches on a String array. I've tried multiple different approaches and I can't seem to get it to work.

My current code is this:

```
 public static void searchSinger(Music2[] r, String toFind) {
        int high = r.length;
        int low = -1;
        int probe;
        while (high - low > 1) {
            probe = (high + low) / 2;
            if (r[probe].getSinger().compareTo(toFind) > 0) high = probe;
            else {
                low = probe;
                if (r[probe].getSinger().compareTo(toFind) == 0) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if ((low >= 0) && (r[low].getSinger().compareTo(toFind) == 0)) {
            linearPrint(r, low, toFind);
        } else System.out.println("Not found: " + toFind);
    }


    public static void linearPrint(Music2[] r, int low,
    String toFind) {
        int i;
        int start = -1;
        int end = -1;

        // find starting point of matches
        i = low - 1;
        while ((i >= 0) && (r[i].getSinger().compareTo(toFind) == 0)) {
            start = i;
            i--;
        }
        // find ending point of matches
        i = low + 1;
        while ((i < r.length) && (r[i].getSinger().compareTo(toFind) == 0)) {
            end = i;
            i++;
        }
        // now print out the matches
        for (i = start; i <= end; i++)
        System.out.println(r[i]);
    }
```

And if I call the code such as

```
searchSinger(myLibrary, "Eminem");
```

and Eminem does exist in myLibrary, it will return

```
"Not found: Eminem"
```

So my question is, what am I doing wrong here? I'm really trying to get this to work, but I can't seem to debug it myself.

EDIT:
Here is the sorting algorithm I'm using:

```
public static void selectionSort(Music2[] list) {
    int i;
    int k;
    int posmax;
    Music2 temp;
        for (i = list.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            // find largest element in the i elements
            posmax = 0;
            for (k = 0; k <= i; k++) {
                if (list[k].getYear() > list[posmax].getYear()) posmax = k;
            }
            // swap the largest with the position i
            // now the item is in its proper location
            temp = list[i];
            list[i] = list[posmax];
            list[posmax] = temp;
        }
    }
```

Comment: what'd be the point of this? to do a binary search, you need an alread-sorted input. once you find the first incidence of your search word, it's a simple matter to check the next/previous entries to see if there's any more - but that's not a binary search anymore, that's simple linear array/list traversal

Comment: The algorithm looks correct to me. I would theorize that either the input isn't sorted right, or it does not contain the string you are looking for (or, perhaps, it is in a different case, or has a space or a dot you are not noticing or something like that).

Comment: I'm using a selection sort for the sorting of the array, I'll add that to the post.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you sort it by year ... and then search by singer. 
It does not work like this.

Imagine a phone book. It is sorted by last name, right? Does it help to search for all people whose phone ends with 7? Of course not ... But if you wanted to look up all Simths, that would be easy, you could do binary search.

For the binary sort to work, your array needs to be sorted by the same ordering you use when searching. In short, if you are searching for singer,  it needs to be sorted by singer.